# Finding Linear Equations from a given Solution Set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

I have a solution set given in the following way and I have to find a system of linear equations with 4 variables.

$\Bigg\{
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{1} 
\\m_{2} 
\\m_{3} 
\\m_{4}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$ +
$  
\begin{align}
    m_1\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3} \\
           x_{4}
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$ +
$\begin{align}
    m_2\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3} \\
           x_{4}
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$;$\:$ $m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{R} \Bigg\}$ $\subseteq \mathbb{R^4}$

I have tried to construct the equations in like this:

$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{1} 
\\m_{2} 
\\m_{3} 
\\m_{4}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$ =
$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} 
\\x_{2} 
\\x_{3} 
\\x_{4}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$ +
$  
\begin{align}
    m_1\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3} \\
           x_{4}
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$ +
$\begin{align}
    m_2\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3} \\
           x_{4}
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$

then getting equation for each $m$ in this way :
$m_1 = x_1 +m_1(x_1) + m_2(x_2)$

Now I have set the equations in this manner because there is a solution set for 4 variables namely $m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4$. Now I am not sure if $m_1$ and $m_2$ in my construction $[m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4]^T$ should same as given in the solution set.

I would like to know how to solve such set systems to get linear equations.

P.S: I have not given any example because I want to see how a certain generic solution would look like. If its insufficient mention in comments then I can provide some example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution vector is of the form

$ x = x_0 + t  V_1 + s V_2 $

where $x_0, V_1, V_2 $ are known vectors.

Therefore,

$ (x - x_0) = t V_1 + s V_2 \hspace{48pt} (*)$

We can obtain a linear system in $x$, if we find two vectors $U_1, U_2$ that are orthogonal to both $V_1$ and $V_2$, i.e. we need to solve

$ \begin{bmatrix} V_1^T \\ V_2^T \end{bmatrix} u = 0 $

This will give a solution  $u = c_1 U_1 + c_2 U_2 \hspace{48pt} (**)$

From $(*) , (**) $ , it follows that,

$ U_1^T (x - x_0) = 0 $

$ U_2^T (x - x_0) = 0 $

Therefore, the linear system you're looking for is

$ A x = b $

where

$A = \begin{bmatrix} U_1^T \\ U_2^T \end{bmatrix}, \hspace{12pt} b = \begin{bmatrix} U_1^T x_0 \\ U_2^T x_0 \end{bmatrix} $

As a specific example, if

$x_0 = [1, 0, 1, 0]^T , V_1 = [-2, 3, 0, 0]^T, V_2 = [-3, 0, 4, 3]^T $

Then we will solve the system

$\begin{bmatrix} -2 && 3 && 0 && 0 \\ -3 && 0 && 4 && 3 \end{bmatrix} u = 0 $

Using Gauss-Jordan reduction, the matrix is reduced to

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && -\dfrac{4}{3} && -1 \\ 0 && 1 && -\dfrac{8}{9} && - \dfrac{2}{3} \end{bmatrix} $

From which,

$U_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 12 \\ 8 \\ 9 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

$U_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $

Now $U_1^T x_0 = 21 $ and $U_2^T x_0 = 3 $, therefore the linear system is:

$\begin{bmatrix} 12 && 8 && 9 && 0 \\ 3 && 2 && 0 && 3 \end{bmatrix} x = \begin{bmatrix} 21 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: {
$\left(\begin {array}{ccc}1\\0\\1\\0\end{array}\right)$ + $x_1$
$\left(\begin {array}{ccc}-2\\3\\0\\0\end{array}\right)$ + 
$x_2$$
\left(\begin {array}{ccc}-3\\0\\4\\3\end{array}\right)$ } is it possible if you can explain with this example?

Comment: @lemniscate Yes. Check the updated solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)